# how to get the province name with giving lat lng?

Tags: google-maps

I get the lat&lng info of a certain place ,and I want to get the city or province name where this place lies,how can I do that?

for example ,with this lat&lng: Point(39.904667  116.408198) in beijing China,I want to get beijing.

Does google map has any api can do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you describe is called [Reverse Geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding). Google provides two APIs for that: A [JavaScript API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding), and a [Web Service API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Example using the web service:

> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=39.904667,116.408198&sensor=false

Response (using JSON, but can also return XML):

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "types": [ "street_address" ],
    "formatted_address": "2号 Zhengyi Rd, Dongcheng, Beijing, China",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "2号",
      "short_name": "2号",
      "types": [ "street_number" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Zhengyi Rd",
      "short_name": "Zhengyi Rd",
      "types": [ "route" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Dongcheng",
      "short_name": "Dongcheng",
      "types": [ "sublocality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Beijing",
      "short_name": "Beijing",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Beijing",
      "short_name": "Beijing",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "China",
      "short_name": "CN",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 39.9042110,
        "lng": 116.4074130
      },
      "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 39.9010634,
          "lng": 116.4042654
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 39.9073586,
          "lng": 116.4105606
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "types": [ "sublocality", "political" ],
    "formatted_address": "Dongcheng, Beijing, China",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "Dongcheng",
      "short_name": "Dongcheng",
      "types": [ "sublocality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Beijing",
      "short_name": "Beijing",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Beijing",
      "short_name": "Beijing",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "China",
      "short_name": "CN",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 39.9284190,
        "lng": 116.4161900
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 39.9000758,
          "lng": 116.3868896
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 39.9754256,
          "lng": 116.4471843
        }
      },
      "bounds": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 39.9000758,
          "lng": 116.3868896
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 39.9754256,
          "lng": 116.4471843
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ],
    "formatted_address": "Beijing, China",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "Beijing",
      "short_name": "Beijing",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "China",
      "short_name": "CN",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 39.9046670,
        "lng": 116.4081980
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 39.4432527,
          "lng": 115.4203742
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 41.0608685,
          "lng": 117.5055691
        }
      },
      "bounds": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 39.4432527,
          "lng": 115.4203742
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 41.0608685,
          "lng": 117.5055691
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "types": [ "locality", "political" ],
    "formatted_address": "Beijing, China",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "Beijing",
      "short_name": "Beijing",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Beijing",
      "short_name": "Beijing",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "China",
      "short_name": "CN",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 39.9046670,
        "lng": 116.4081980
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 39.6612714,
          "lng": 116.0119343
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 40.2164962,
          "lng": 116.7829835
        }
      },
      "bounds": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 39.6612714,
          "lng": 116.0119343
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 40.2164962,
          "lng": 116.7829835
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "types": [ "country", "political" ],
    "formatted_address": "China",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "China",
      "short_name": "CN",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 35.8616600,
        "lng": 104.1953970
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 17.9996000,
          "lng": 73.4994137
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.5609740,
          "lng": 134.7728100
        }
      },
      "bounds": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 17.9996000,
          "lng": 73.4994137
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.5609740,
          "lng": 134.7728100
        }
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

And this is an example using the JavaScript API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps Reverse Geocoding</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       zoom: 12
   });

   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

   geocoder.geocode({
      'latLng': new google.maps.LatLng(39.904667, 116.408198)
   }, 
   function(results, status) {
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map
         });
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
         infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
         infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
   });

   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Reverse Geocoding]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Google Maps, but geonames (http://www.geonames.org/) might have what you need, especially this one: http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#countrysubdiv